# What does the ℓ notation means in formula about negative sampling and noise contrastive estimation for word2vec skip-gram?

Tags: notation, machine-learning, sampling, neural-networks, noise

I do not know what is the notation, $\ell$, means in the below formula about negative sampling and noise contrastive estimation (NCE) because I don't have a strong math background. Does it stands for log? Is it the ell symbol for sequence space; if so, what does sequence space means here?

Additionally, what does $\mathcal{N}$ means and the bold upper $\mathsf{T}$ means? I always wonder if the authors made mistakes or not.

$$
\sum_{t=1}^{\mathsf{T}}\sum_{c\in c_{t}}\ell(s(w_{t}, w_{c})) + \sum_{n\in \mathcal{N}_{t,c}}\ell(-s(w_{t}, n))
$$

This from the book, Deep Learning for NLP and Speech Recognition (Kamath et al., 2019) in the 5th Chapter for Distribution Representations, the authors go over word2vec and negative sampling for skip-gram. In particular, they explain the differences between negative sampling and NCE.

Attaching Page for More Context

> [image]

Along with the following articles:

1. NCE https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.01812.pdf
2. Negative sampling https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4546.pdf

Comment: $\ell$ seems to not be used earlier in that book (including the Notation section), nor used again in the rest of that Chapter 5, nor used in either of the articles you link. Aside from noting that equation (5.12) looks a lot like equation (5.11) and so there may be a relationship there, I don't think there are any other clues in the text. You may want to check if there is an errata for the text and email the author(s) if not.